# Excel worksheet for Coordinate transformation between EPSG:31467 and EPSG:25832?

Tags: coordinate-system, excel

for offline use I have been asked to provide a coordinate transformation worksheet in excel that converts between EPSG:31467 and EPSG:25832 and also WGS84. Has anyone any experience with something like this?

Comment: Is Excel a requirement for this? You could do this with an HTML Page & Proj4js for the conversion.

Comment: Have you tried if the Excel sheet from  http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/navigation-technology/os-net/coordinate-spreadsheet.html is of any use?

Comment: actually HTML and Proj4 could be a solution. Do I need to run a tomcat server for that?

Comment: @RobertBuckley: Not really.Even though it is not recommended,  You could have the entire code within one single  HTML  file if  portability is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page http://www.vermessung-und-ortung-mit-satelliten.de/datumstrans.html leads you to two excel sheets that do the conversion you want:

http://www.vermessung-und-ortung-mit-satelliten.de/excel/transformationen/datumstransformation/GK_DHDN_transformiert_nach_UTM_ETRS.xls

http://www.vermessung-und-ortung-mit-satelliten.de/excel/transformationen/datumstransformation/UTM_ETRS_transformiert_nach_GK_DHDN.xls

I have not yet tested the quality of the transformation.